# CsvHelper and IEnumerable<object> issue with writing of multiple records into a CSV file

Tags: c#, ienumerable, asp.net-core-3.1, csvhelper

I am trying to create a CSV file with `IEnumerable<object>` using CsvHelper, with multiple rows. When I pass the data to the function that creates the CSV file and the count of the `IEnumerable<object>` is greater than 1, it throws an error:

> Types that inherit IEnumerable cannot be auto mapped. Did you
> accidentally call GetRecord or WriteRecord which acts on a single
> record instead of calling GetRecords or WriteRecords which acts on a
> list of records?

The CsvWriter works perfectly when there is one element, however, there are occasions where the `IEnumerable<object>` can have up to 96+ items in it and they need to go into one file. The desired outcome is that the contents of the `IEnumerable<object>` can be written to a CSV file, preferably with CsvHelper.

```
public void SaveCsvData(IEnumerable<object> csvDataToWriteToFile, string path)
{
       CsvConfiguration csvConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
       {
           HasHeaderRecord = false
       };
            
       using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(path, false))
       using (CsvWriter csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, csvConfig))
       {
           csvWriter.WriteRecords(csvDataToWriteToFile);               
       }         
 }
```

I have tried adding the following:

```
foreach (var item in csvDataToWriteToFile.ToList())
{                   
      csvWriter.WriteRecords(csvDataToWriteToFile);
}
```

Also...

```
 foreach (var item in csvDataToWriteToFile.ToList())
 {                   
      csvWriter.WriteRecord(item);
 }
```

Can anyone suggest how I can remedy the ability to write multiple items from an object into one file, as I cannot work out how to do it?

The reason I haven't mapped the class is that I have a very, very large pivot that has multiple types of time resolutions and the pivot has to be dynamic in nature.

Here is the Pivot:

```
public static IEnumerable<object> PivotH(List<CsvModel> csvData)
        {
            csvData.ForEach(x =>
            {
                x.ReadingDate = csvData.Select(x => x.ReadingDate).Min();
            });

            List<CsvModel> data = (from x in csvData
                                   group x by new
                                   {
                                       x.Meter_Identifier,
                                       x.Units,
                                       x.ReadingDate
                                   }
                                         into grp
                                   select new CsvModel
                                   {
                                       Meter_Identifier = grp.Key.Meter_Identifier,
                                       Units = grp.Key.Units,
                                       ReadingDate = grp.Key.ReadingDate,
                                       #region Pivot 
                                       r1 = grp.Where(i => i.ReadingTime.ToString() == "01:00").Select(x => x.ReadingValue).FirstOrDefault(),
                                       r2 = grp.Where(i => i.ReadingTime.ToString() == "02:00").Select(x => x.ReadingValue).FirstOrDefault(),
                                       r3 = grp.Where(i => i.ReadingTime.ToString() == "03:00").Select(x => x.ReadingValue).FirstOrDefault(),
                                       r4 = grp.Where(i => i.ReadingTime.ToString() == "04:00").Select(x => x.ReadingValue).FirstOrDefault(),
                                       r5 = grp.Where(i => i.ReadingTime.ToString() == "05:00").Select(x => x.ReadingValue).FirstOrDefault(),
                                       r6 = grp.Where(i => i.ReadingTime.ToString() == "06:00").Select(x => x.ReadingValue).FirstOrDefault(),
                                       r7 = grp.Where(i => i.ReadingTime.ToString() == "07:00").Select(x => x.ReadingValue).FirstOrDefault(),
                                       r8 = grp.Where(i => i.ReadingTime.ToString() == "08:00").Select(x => x.ReadingValue).FirstOrDefault(),
                                       r9 = grp.Where(i => i.ReadingTime.ToString() == "09:00").Select(x => x.ReadingValue).FirstOrDefault(),
                                       r10 = grp.Where(i => i.ReadingTime.ToString() == "10:00").Select(x => x.ReadingValue).FirstOrDefault(),
                                       r11 = grp.Where(i => i.ReadingTime.ToString() == "11:00").Select(x => x.ReadingValue).FirstOrDefault(),
                                       r12 = grp.Where(i => i.ReadingTime.ToString() == "12:00").Select(x => x.ReadingValue).FirstOrDefault(),
                                       r13 = grp.Where(i => i.ReadingTime.ToString() == "13:00").Select(x => x.ReadingValue).FirstOrDefault(),
                                       r14 = grp.Where(i => i.ReadingTime.ToString() == "14:00").Select(x => x.ReadingValue).FirstOrDefault(),
                                       r15 = grp.Where(i => i.ReadingTime.ToString() == "15:00").Select(x => x.ReadingValue).FirstOrDefault(),
                                       r16 = grp.Where(i => i.ReadingTime.ToString() == "16:00").Select(x => x.ReadingValue).FirstOrDefault(),
                                       r17 = grp.Where(i => i.ReadingTime.ToString() == "17:00").Select(x => x.ReadingValue).FirstOrDefault(),
                                       r18 = grp.Where(i => i.ReadingTime.ToString() == "18:00").Select(x => x.ReadingValue).FirstOrDefault(),
                                       r19 = grp.Where(i => i.ReadingTime.ToString() == "19:00").Select(x => x.ReadingValue).FirstOrDefault(),
                                       r20 = grp.Where(i => i.ReadingTime.ToString() == "20:00").Select(x => x.ReadingValue).FirstOrDefault(),
                                       r21 = grp.Where(i => i.ReadingTime.ToString() == "21:00").Select(x => x.ReadingValue).FirstOrDefault(),
                                       r22 = grp.Where(i => i.ReadingTime.ToString() == "22:00").Select(x => x.ReadingValue).FirstOrDefault(),
                                       r23 = grp.Where(i => i.ReadingTime.ToString() == "23:00").Select(x => x.ReadingValue).FirstOrDefault(),
                                       r24 = grp.Where(i => i.ReadingTime.ToString() == "00:00").Select(x => x.ReadingValue).FirstOrDefault()
                                       #endregion
                                   }).ToList();

            var returnData = (from x in data
                              select new
                              {
                                  Meter_Identifier = x.Meter_Identifier,
                                  Units = x.Units,
                                  ReadingDate = x.ReadingDate,
                                  r1 = x.r1,
                                  r2 = x.r2,
                                  r3 = x.r3,
                                  r4 = x.r4,
                                  r5 = x.r5,
                                  r6 = x.r6,
                                  r7 = x.r7,
                                  r8 = x.r8,
                                  r9 = x.r9,
                                  r10 = x.r10,
                                  r11 = x.r11,
                                  r12 = x.r12,
                                  r13 = x.r13,
                                  r14 = x.r14,
                                  r15 = x.r15,
                                  r16 = x.r16,
                                  r17 = x.r17,
                                  r18 = x.r18,
                                  r19 = x.r19,
                                  r20 = x.r20,
                                  r21 = x.r21,
                                  r22 = x.r22,
                                  r23 = x.r23,
                                  r24 = x.r24
                              }).ToList();

            return returnData;
        }
```

This is the **small** pivot. The CsvModel has 1440+ properties in it, for different time resolutions over a 24 hour period in minutes. I then group the data, based on the chosen resolution, in the example above, this is for one hour periods.

TIA

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly your dynamic object looks like, but have you tried using `ExpandoObject`, like the [example](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/writing/write-dynamic-objects) on their site shows?

Comment: I tried that and using regular dynamic objects and both seem to work with the code you provided.

Comment: I just added the pivot in the question. The issue I have is that the CsvMOdel class has every minute of the day as a property, and when only want hours (24 slots), the CSV helper prints all 1440 in the CSV. Doing it anonymous types, helped manage the dynamic nature of the users choice in time resolution

Comment: I have tried the suggestions and I still get the original error. var records = new 
     List<dynamic>();
                dynamic record = new ExpandoObject();
                record = csvDataToWriteToFile;
                foreach (var item in record)
                {
                    records.AddRange(item);
                }

Comment: I have noticed that the way I group the data in the pivot, it ends up having an array of an array (kind of), so I add the loop to make sure the elements are in the highest level.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning a subset of your `CsvModel` object and trying to write that out, what you can do instead is return the entire object and create a `ClassMap` for each of your pivots. You can specify what fields you want outputted in each map.

```
public void SaveCsvData(IEnumerable<CsvModel> csvDataToWriteToFile, string path, ClassMap<CsvModel> map)
{
       CsvConfiguration csvConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
       {
           HasHeaderRecord = false
       };

       using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(path, false))
       using (CsvWriter csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, csvConfig))
       {
           csvWriter.Context.RegisterClassMap(map);
           csvWriter.WriteRecords(csvDataToWriteToFile);               
       }         
 }
```

See CsvHelper's example [here](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/mapping-by-index)

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63946479) to [Writing only selected columns to CSV-file using CsvHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31748272)

Comment: RegisterClassMap is not recognised.

Comment: It appears that this is only for the reader.

Comment: I moved `RegisterClassMap` to the csvWriter, see if that works.

Comment: Based on that I would need to write over 1,000 class maps. I guess I can't do it with CsvHelper. Back to the old fashioned datatable!

Answer (score 0):

While not an answer, I was not able to achieve what I needed, so I used a DataTable instead.